# Nested structures and Typedef

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, nested, structure, typedef

Im trying to print no_routes through structures and typedef in C. But the below code is segmentation fault

```
typedef struct RDI
{
    int no_routes;

}RD;


struct Os_class
{

    RD os_rdi[10];

}*OS_CL;


void Initiate_CL()
{
   OS_CL->os_rdi[0].no_routes = 10;

}


main()
{

Initiate_CL();

//printf( " CL %d",OS_CL->os_rdi[0].no_routes);
}
```

an use typedef to give a name to user defined data type as well. For example you can use typedef with structure to define a new data type and then use that data type to define structure variables directly as follows:

Answer (score 1):

You are using `OS_CL` (which is pointer) but never allocated memory for it.

```
void Initiate_CL()
{
    OS_CL = malloc(sizeof(Os_class)); <-- allocation.

    OS_CL->os_rdi[0].no_routes = 10;
}
```

Make sure you de-allocate memory with `free` after use to avoid memory leak.